# auto compile the javascript source codes using closure-compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am using the closure-compiler.jar to compress my sources codes.

And we use the `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATION` model,so we have to be careful when we write the codes.

For example, we have to use the

`obj["prop"]` instead of `obj.prop` to export the property 'prop'.

So in order to make sure the compressed codes work, we will compress it once we modify the codes.

However,our project is under develpment,so the modifiation is frequent.

Once we update the code (even add a char) we have to run the

```
java -jar xx.jar ......
```

So I wonder if there is any tool can monitor the change of the source code,then compress them and  make them formatted pretty in windows (like winLess for less) ?

Comment: Read: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/YU89mbuI1g0

Comment: hi I can not access the group site. can you do ome a favor to post the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plovr.com/ seems to be a favorite among those I talk to.

Comment: Does this use Google's Closer Compiler, or its own?

Comment: It uses Closure Compiler.